# ui-select selected not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm currently using `ui-select` component in AngularJS.

```
<ui-select ng-model="tipData.category" search-enabled="false" name="category" required="required" class="orange-site-color-select custom-select">
  <ui-select-match><span class="ui-select-result">{{$select.selected}}</span></ui-select-match>
  <ui-select-choices repeat="tipcat in tipCategory"><span ng-bind-html="tipcat.name"></span></ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

I'd like to know how can I implement auto select value displayed in that `ui-select` as retrieving data (**just id**) from database and displayed in that `ui-select`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
<select ng-model="selectedCountry">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
 <option ng-repeat="x in chooseCountries" value="{{x.countryId}}"  >{{x.name}}</option>
</select>  
</div>
```

And script code

```
 var app = angular.module('main', []);
 app.controller('DemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.chooseCountries=[
{countryId : 1, name : "France - Mainland", desc: "some description" },
{countryId : 2, name : "Gibraltar", desc: "some description"},
{countryId : 3, name : "Malta", desc: "some description"}
];   
 $scope.selectedCountry =  $scope.chooseCountries[1].countryId.toString();   
 });
```

Comment: I'm using `ui-select`

Answer (score 0):

You can use selected property.

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" ng-app="main">
  <select ng-model="selectedCountry">
<option value="">Select Account</option>
      <option ng-repeat="x in chooseCountries" value="{{x.countryId}}"  selected="{{x.name}}=Malta">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>  
</div>
```

Comment: again, I'm using `ui-select`